# Excel Tick Marks chaning display of data

Tags: excel, charts

I am struggling with Excel charts & tick marks.
My data is in the following format:

time: 24/12/2019  18:00:00 (2k+ lines)

Value 1: Some number

Value 2: Threshold (3000)

So my chart is like this:

[image]

The threshold line is not starting with my data so I select the X-Axis and mark "On the Tick Marks" and then excel breaks my chart like this:

[image]

I must mention my data is NOT from a full month like 1-30 but I tried having a full month but that did not change anything, also tried having secondary axis with no luck.

Never see this one before.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:** Adding image for sample data

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data. I don't see how what you describe corresponds to the charts provided

Comment: Hello Nomad, see my edit with the data I'm using to create the chart.

Comment: Try adding two more rows with dates before the first month and after the last month. Leave those rows blank except for the "Threshold" column, where you insert 3000 as usual

Comment: Added two lines in the start and end but the threshold line does not fill the chart, selecting the "On Tick Marks" gives the same result hidding values.